# Is there a way to turn off startup welcome screen?

Tags: interface

[image]
I dont really need it and its kind of a nuisance.

Comment: User preferences -> Interface -> Bottom right...

Comment: not the place for an answer, but thank you too :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's right here in the Preferences (press `Save user settings` before restarting to test):

[image: "Show Splash" checkbox on bottom-right corner of User Preferences > Interface]

Comment: And don't forget to 'Save User Settings' to keep it that way.

Comment: I was checking the preferences for like 10 minutes :D i'm blind. Thanks. Eh, i have to wait 10 minutes to mark the answer as solved... Weird.

Comment: Where did it move to in 3.3? -- **Edit:** Oh gosh -- it's at the very top of the `Interface` menu -- I kept skipping over it without realizing because it's the *very first* checkbox. 